# Is it possible that $y'(x) = x^2 - y^2$ has a second solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems

While testing [Physics-informed neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics-informed_neural_networks) I discovered that IVP

$$ y'(x) = x^2 - y^2 $$
$$ y(0) = 2.5 $$

possibly has a second solution. I'm quite sure that my model once found a very good approximation (I discarded it because I wasn't looking for it) of this "new" solution. But I cannot recreate it since, so I started wondering whether this IVP actually has a second solution.

My best attempt so far at finding the second solution is shown on this graph as a blue curve.

[image]

Curves on the graph are:

- Blue curve - best neural network solution
- Red curve - known solution found with a RK45 numerical method
- Green curve - actual derivative of NN solution
- Orange curve - value of $f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$ computed from the NN solution

Is it possible to check if that potential second solution actually exists or does not exist, without finding it?

I know that this IVP is a form of Riccati equation and its known solution [has a (not simple) analytical form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%28x%29%20%3D%20x%5E2%20-%20y%5E2%20%2C%20y%280%29%20%3D%202.5). So if the potential second solution actually exists, I am wondering if it has maybe been already found or the existing analytical solution can be adapted to fit the potential "second" solution.

Comment: How come your second solution does not seem to satisfy $y(0)=2.5$?

Comment: There must be something wrong in your code: between $x = 0.5$ and $1.0$, $x^2 - y^2$ is positive so that means the blue curve cannot be decreasing there. Also, from using Euler's method, all of the curves with $y(0) = 2.3, 2.4, \cdots, 2.7$ follow the shape of the original solution.

Comment: @TobyMak I've added a more detailed description of curves. Orange curve is positive because the solution is not perfect (because it's my best attempt at recreating the potential perfect solution). But possibly the blue curve could be modified for the green and orange curves to match.

Comment: @wimi That's just the "property" of machine learning, the learning algorithm gives a slightly better fit of solution gradient at the expense of initial condition being imperfect.

Comment: What do you mean by "slightly better fit"? The gradient of your proposed solution is miles away from what it should be. The only thing that is happening here is that your neural network outputs a completely wrong solution. You should not blindly trust neural networks

Comment: @wimi I expressed my thoughts unclearly. The loss function is a sum of loss from fitting IC and gradient. What I meant is that model "found" the total loss local minimum by reducing the loss from (imperfect) gradient fit at the expense of increasing the loss from IC fit. I'm far from trusting, the NN blindly - that's basically why I've written this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-2y$ are continuous functions of $x$ and $y$ in the region $-a<x<a$ and $2.5-b<y<2.5+b$ for any positive real numbers $a$ and $b$. Due to the existence and uniqueness theorem for 1st order ODEs (See e.g. S. L. Ross), there is a unique solution of the IVP $y'=x^2-y^2$, $y'(0)=2.5$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That confirms I must have misremembered the "second" solution I've seen and it was just some nn-generated rubbish.